# Can't reach Spark webserver on localhost. Unable to establish loopback connection. Neither in administrator command line

Tags: maven, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin, spark-java

I'm doing this tutorial: [Spark tutorial](https://sparktutorials.github.io/2015/04/03/spark-lombok-jackson-reduce-boilerplate.html)

After starting the webserver with

```
mvn compile && mvn exec:java
```

Nothing happens for a minute, then I get a lot of errors: [errors](http://pastebin.com/BD3Yh6W0)

I use the command line in administrator mode. I've turnedd off fully the Avast security and the comodo firewall. But I still got the same error. Also no response for localhost:4567/posts .

I'm sorry for the pastebin but the error is just way too long, and I don't know which part is necessary or unnecessary.

Here is my code:

```
import static spark.Spark.get;
import static spark.Spark.post;
import spark.Request;
import spark.Response;
import spark.Route;

public class Main {
    public static void main( String[] args) {
        get("/posts", (req, res) -> {
            return "Hello Sparkingly World!";
        });
    }
}
```

And my pom.xml is the same as in the tutorial except the line me.tomassetti.BlogService</mainClass> --> (I commented it out.)

Comment: My guess: If you are using Eclipse IDE, just start a new Maven Project, leave the <build> section in the pom.xml file as is, just copy the dependencies, code the BlogService class, and Run.